# How to manage 'upper' and 'lower' triangle separately in corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I want to get upper triangle with 'p-values' and lower triangle without them. I have tried some codes but couldn't get correct responses. Here is the code I've tried.

```
corrplot.mixed(cr, p.mat = res1$p, insig = "label_sig",sig.level = c(.01, .05), pch.cex = 0.8, pch.col = "black", lower.col = col, order="hclust", tl.col = "black", tl.cex=.6, upper.col = col)
```

Where can I add the code that cancels lower triangle p-values?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an easy way that uses the 'add' comment. We can manage both triangles individually and merge them with the 'add' code. No need to use corrplot.mixed anymore.